# Array to String Conversion Error Symfony 3

Tags: mysql, symfony

I have two tables Project and User and a join table ProjectUser. I am creating a query to select the users under a certain projectName I couldn't do that so I created a query to select the id of the project according to its name from the project table
            ``` public function findName($projectName){
    $query=$this->getEntityManager()
    ->createQuery("SELECT p.id FROM SocialProProjectBundle:Project p WHERE            ``p.name='$projectName'");
        return $query->getResult();
    } ```

and then a query to select the users through the project id

```
public function findProjectUsers($pId){
 $query=$this->getEntityManager()
 ->createQuery(
 "SELECT pu, u FROM SocialProProjectBundle:ProjectUser pu JOIN      SocialProDefaultBundle: User u WHERE pu.project = '$pId'"
        );
    return $query->getResult();
}
```

but I always get Notice: Array to string conversion !!!!!

Here is how I called them in the controller

```
 $projectName = $request->get('projectName');
    echo($projectName);
    $projectId=$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SocialProMeetingBundle:meetingUser')->findName($projectName);
    echo(count($projectId));
    foreach($projectId as $pId) {
        $pus = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('SocialProMeetingBundle:meetingUser')->findProjectUsers($pId);
    }
   $response = "<select class=\"select2_multiple form-control\" multiple=\"multiple\">";
    foreach ($pus as $user) {//($i=0;$i<count($pus);$i++)
        $name[]=array($user->getFirstName());
     }
    $response = $response . "<option>$name</option>";
    $response = $response."</select> ";
    return new Response($response);
    //return($pus);
    //call repository function
}
```

Comment: Also every foreach loop does not return a result !!! when I create an object inside the loop and I use it outside of it I always get undefined variable

Comment: `$name` is an array and you try to display it: `<option>$name</option>`.

Comment: @malcolm I've tried it this way                                                                                                 foreach ($pus as $user) {//($i=0;$i<count($pus);$i++)
            $name=$user->getFirstName();
            $response = $response . "<option>$name</option>";
         } and still the same problem

Comment: The Notice says that the error is in the query

Comment: Because your `$pId` is a object or array not string.

Comment: @malcolm could you tell me how to fix it please?

Comment: $pId is only defined in the controller as an element of $projectId which is supposed to be the id of the $projectName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi: for the for loop question you had on how to solve it, use this code:

```
$response = "<select class=\"select2_multiple form-control\" multiple=\"multiple\">";
foreach($pus as $user){
    $response . "<option>" . $user->getFirstName() . "</option>";
}
$response = $response."</select> ";
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found to this is that I avoided the $pId and found the query capable to select the users through the $projectName Here it Is :

```
 public function findProjectUsers($projectName){
    $query=$this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
            "SELECT u.firstName FROM SocialProDefaultBundle:User u, SocialProProjectBundle:Project p, SocialProProjectBundle:ProjectUser pu WHERE u.id = pu.user AND p.id=pu.project AND p.name='$projectName'");
    return $query->getResult();
}
```