# How can I use a variable in a mysql query?

Tags: jquery, mysql, function, symfony, variables

This is my function:

```
  public function findByIdJoinedToCategory($id)
     {
         $query = $this->getEntityManager()
             ->createQuery(
                 'SELECT a, b
                 FROM App\Entity\Products a
                 JOIN a.productgroup b
                 WHERE a.id = 2');
     }
```

I simply try to replace `2` with the variable `$id`. But I do not succeed:

```
  public function findByIdJoinedToCategory($id)
     {
         $query = $this->getEntityManager()
             ->createQuery(
                 'SELECT a, b
                 FROM App\Entity\Products a
                 JOIN a.productgroup b
                 WHERE a.id = $id');
     }
```

I get the error message:

> [Syntax Error] line 0, col 125: Error: Expected Literal, got '$'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, when placing special characters such as a new line or vars in a string you need to use double quotes.

To place a var in a string you need to concatenate it into the string as follows:

```
'SELECT a, b
FROM App\Entity\Products a
JOIN a.productgroup b
WHERE a.id = '.$id
```

You are able to able to place the var inside of the string as follows:

```
"SELECT a, b
FROM App\Entity\Products a
JOIN a.productgroup b
WHERE a.id = $id"
```

However, you may find the following more readable:

```
"SELECT a, b
FROM App\Entity\Products a
JOIN a.productgroup b
WHERE a.id = {$id}"
```

Comment: I think it is working. I get the error now `Notice: Array to string conversion` but I think this is another issue

Comment: Yes that means `$id` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

it has to concat the string i think.
try this :

```
public function findByIdJoinedToCategory($id)
     {
         $query = $this->getEntityManager()
             ->createQuery(
                 "SELECT a, b
                 FROM App\Entity\Products a
                 JOIN a.productgroup b
                 WHERE a.id ='$id'");
     }
```

Comment: try this, i hope it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42188422/array-to-string-conversion-error-symfony-3/42190101
try read this thread, hope it can solve